# Organizing data to feed random forests

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-mining, dataset, random-forest

I'm willing to apply machine learning with `R` (I will start with random forests then maybe have a look at NNs) on some data, but I don't know where to start, probably because I don't know which words to put on my problem and what to google for.

My data consist in a set of events of type A, each of which contains both some specific variables and a (variable) number of elements of type B with their own variables.

A typical example of such data would be horse racing : each race has its own parameters along with a list of horses and their own parameters.

Now, of course the training has to be done on each element of type A independently, so tutorials using basic `iris` data won't work — or at least I don't understand how to apply them on events of type A instead of elements of type B.

How should I organize my data set or feed it to `randomForest` ?  Or which keywords should I use to find relevant documentation on this kind of topic ?  (I tried "grouped data" without much success…)

NB : For a start I can discard the common variables of each A event, if needed.  But still every B element has to be considered equal of other B elements *inside* a single A event, and independently from other A events.

**Update :** I've found a workaround which may work in my particular situation (still to be tested, my DB needs reorganization).  The workaround is to consider parameters of the A events as parameters of each B element, so the problem simply becomes a set of B elements.  However I'm not satisfied with this solution and anyway I'm not sure it could be applicable to other similar problems, the question is still open.

Comment: It would help to give more information about your specific task. What are you trying to predict? Are the total number of Bs small? Will you observe every B in your training set that you'll ever observe in your test set?

Comment: Classification or regression over the B elements inside an A event, depending of the more efficient — both may be relevant.  I would like to consider each B element independently from other A events, so even though it may not be the case in reality, in practical the number of Bs is larger than the number of As and elements from the test set will differ from the training set.  And there are only a fairly small number of B elements per A event.